# How to make external REST calls from ABP Angular 6

Tags: angular, cors, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am having problems integrating with public **REST API's** from my `AspNetBoilerplate angular app`.

Regardless of which external service I call, I get **CORS Error** back because the call gets the pragma in the header.

This is the error I get in the console:

```
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

This happens in the simplest of calls:

```
this.http.get('http://maps.google.com/places').subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

I have a feeling that it's the `HTTP interceptor` which is bugging me here but I need guidance on how I should go about this in a ABP way.

I have made angular `injectable services` to contain my HTTP client requests of course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open appsettings.json in your Projectname.Web.Host project and add actually host from which you connecting into CorsOrigins property. In your case it is http://localhost:4200

```
"App": {
    "ServerRootAddress": "http://localhost:4200/",
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://localhost:4201/",
    "CorsOrigins": "http://localhost:4200"
},
```